# Is it possible to run selenium from <py-script> in html document

Tags: html, selenium, pyscript

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

I found out that after this line it doesn't run anymore
(code works in .py file so I think I imported everything)
Solutions?

Comment: Have you seen [here](https://github.com/custom-components/pyscript/discussions/177#discussioncomment-1565421)? That discussion basically spells out why this is a hurdle at that time. A lot of the fancier things that aren't pure Python or don't install the specific way pyscript needs at this time won't work yet. This is all very experimental and changing rapidly.

Comment: Selenium runs outside the browser not inside. You cannot import Selenium code into a browser application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot import Selenium code into a browser application!!!!