# can i use selenium with pyscript?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pyscript

I tried to run this code but it gives me an error, how can I solve it using selenium? is it possible to use selenium with pyscript? I tried on a random site like "https://www.google.it/"

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pyscript prova</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    <py-config>
        packages = ["selenium"]
    </py-config>
</head>
<body>
    <py-script>
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
wbe= webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    
wbe.get("https://www.google.it/")
    
gmail= wbe.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="gb"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a').text
    
print(gmail)
    </py-script>
</body>

</html>
```

i get this error and i don't know how to fix it :

```
(most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.10/_pyodide/_base.py", line 460, in eval_code
    .run(globals, locals)
  File "/lib/python3.10/_pyodide/_base.py", line 306, in run
    coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
  File "<exec>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.service = service if service else Service()
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 44, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/service.py", line 49, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.port = port or utils.free_port()
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/utils.py", line 36, in free_port
    free_socket.listen(5)
OSError: [Errno 138] Not supported
```

Comment: Duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72363728/8508004) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74035234/8508004) & [here](https://community.anaconda.cloud/t/how-to-use-selenium-with-pyscript/22115/2).